# Static code splitting with Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I really have trouble with Webpack's code splitting features. Can someone help me with the following concrete example?

### Split bundle into base and extension

Most parts of my app only require `lodash` as an external dependency. Let's say there's just a single file `base.js`:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

console.log(_.toUpper('Hello world!'));
```

However one part of the app also requires `moment`. Let's again think of a single file `extension.js`:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as moment from 'moment';

console.log(_.toUpper(moment().format()));
```

Now I want to bundle this up to get *two* distinct files

- `base.bundle.js` containing `base.js` and `lodash`
- `extension.bundle.js` containing `extension.js` and `moment`

On most pages I'll only include `base.bundle.js` and expect to only see a single line of console output. On some pages I'll include both bundles, though, and expect to see both lines of console output.

Is this possible? How can I achieve such a setup?

### What I tried so far

- Simply defining two different entry points will add `lodash` to both bundles.

  ```
  entry: {
      base: './src/base.js',
      extension: './src/extension.js'
  }
  ```
- Defining two different entry points with a simple `splitChunks` optimization will build four `.bundle.js` files instead of two:

  ```
  entry: {
      base: './src/base.js',
      extension: './src/extension.js'
  },
  optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all'
      }
  }
  ```
- Adding both files via the same entry point and defining an explicit chunkGroup for the extension bundle will generate two `.bundle.js` files with the right chunks inside each. However, with this approach it isn't possible to use `base.bundle.js` standalone (no console outputs altogether).

  ```
  entry: {
      base: ['./src/base.js', './src/extension.js']
  },
  optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
              default: false,
              commons: {
                  chunks: 'all',
                  name: 'extension',
                  test: /extension\.js|moment/
              }
          }
      }
  },
  ```